# Why this errors with PSSets in psmatrix?

Tags: pstricks, psmatrix

I´m starting with diagrams, and I have any errors with this code:
(edited after Herbert´s comment)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathpazo}       % Fuente MathPazo
% ----------------------  PSTRICKS ---------------
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-3dplot,pst-node,pst-tree,pst-grad,pst-coil,pst-text,pst-3d,pst-eps,pst-fill,pstricks-add,multido}
%\input{pssettings.tex}
\begin{document}
\psset{framearc=0.2,shadowcolor=black!70,shadowangle=-90,blur=true,fillstyle=solid}‎
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=0.5,colsep=0.5]% defines the distance between two frames
    \psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm}
    &\makebox[2.00]{%
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.15}{Current}
    }
    & \makebox[6cm]{Solución Actual}\\

    &\makebox[2.00]{%
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    }& \makebox{Generar Vecindad}\\
    &\makebox[2.00]{%
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,fillstyle=solid,linestyle=none](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](1,1){0.20}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.20}{Current}
    }& \makebox{Elegir Mejor Vecino}\\

    \psdiabox[shadoÇ=true]{¿Cumple el\\Criterio de Aspiración?}
    &\psdiabox[shadoÇ=true]{¿Está en la \\Lista Tabú?}& \\

    & & \makebox{Aceptar como nueva solución}\\

    }

\end{psmatrix}


\end{document}
```

How Can I do to obtain no errors?

### [image]

### [image]

[image]

How can I do to not overput the contente os makboxes? , obatining a separation between each 2. I_ thought that It was automatic with rowsep

How Can I put the text on the right of the image without being over the frameboxes??

lenght of makebox... Can be set with pt/cm/or without messure?

Comment: what is the contents of `pssettings.tex`? However,  provide minimal examples and do not use external files.

Answer (score 2):

`\makebox` expects a length with a unit. It is a LaTeX command, not a PSTricks one. However, I do not know what you really want to draw. MAybe this helps:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,latexsym}

\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-blur}


%\input{pssettings.tex}
\begin{document}
\psset{framearc=0.2,shadowcolor=black!70,shadowangle=-90}‎
\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1.75,colsep=1.5]% defines the distance between two frames
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,blur,shadow](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.15}{Current}
    & [name=SA] Solución Actual\\
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0,0.65){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](0.65,0.15){0.15}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](-0.75,0.75){0.15}{Current}
    & [name=SS] Generar Vecindad\\
    \psframe[fillcolor=lightgray,linestyle=none,shadow,blur](-1.00,-1.00)(1.00,1.00)
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=pink](1,1){0.20}{Current}
    \cnode[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue](0,0){0.20}{Current}
    & Elegir Mejor Vecino
\end{psmatrix}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it´s that!! It´s the sucesion in the Tabu Search. When I finish, I´m posting the final grpahs that I had have reached with your help.

Comment: What I  can´t understand is why gives me problems in the psset{....}

Comment: TeX reports the line of the input stream which is often not the line of the source code.

Comment: Yes, but your code runs well, and in the mine I have problmes in \psset and \psframe . That is a surprise for me. Never I have problems with this before using psmatrix. Im trying to understand, because I like shadows and other features. http://sensa.square7.ch/fdsfsf0.jpg

Comment: your `\makebox` makes no sense in your example. It can have only horizontal material, no linebreak and no `&` characters. Delete the `\makebox{...}` in your example and try again. Edit your question with the new code, then I'll see what happens.

Comment: ok, I tried, I´m now I obtain no errors if I delete the psset line. But with that line, I have error in that line. I don´t know, but I try in other way... starting from your example

Comment: Your code runs well.... but when I put your code in my bid .tex I obtain  problems in the psset and psframes lines as you can see http://sensa.square7.ch/fsdafdsafdsfsd81.jpg  Instead I pulse ENTER and I have a good result.

Comment: please send me the complete code: herbert@dante.de